# Page load issue in alternate access mapping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, alternate-access-mapping

my sharepoint site in running port 80, with custom master page. Every thing works fine when I access with default url (http://servername/site/sitename/pages/home.aspx) .

but When I access the same site with alternate access mapped URL (portal.domain.com), cutom webpart works fine but all OOB feature stop working.

**i.e.** 
1. Dropdown menu in global navigation does not work.
2. When i open any list or library, nothing display (but at same time i access the default url list/libraries showing data)

**My findings:**

1. I am not able to open any SharePoint site directly from IIS (localhost:80, localhost:14552). It shows page not found 404 error.
2. I not able to access any site via host name (servername:portNumber), to access any web application (Site), I need to mention whole url till site name at least (servername:portNumber/sites/sitename)
3. I am using Http redirection to open the localhost to site url. and at the same time getting following error in event view.

   - System

     - Provider

     [ Name]  System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0

     - EventID 3

     [ Qualifiers]  49154

     Level 2

     Task 5

     Keywords 0x80000000000000

     - TimeCreated

     [ SystemTime]  2016-02-19T21:34:57.000000000Z

     EventRecordID 24894

     Channel Application

     Computer servername-SP.servername.in

     - Security

     [ UserID]  S-1-5-21-322102146-2961557765-1777964600-1234
   - EventData

     System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/56528460 
     System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation. The exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ListDataService..ctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.CreateImplementation(Type serviceType) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) 
     w3wp 
     5028

Adding Screenshot of IIS binding...

Binding of Original Site
[image]

Binding of extended site
[image]

kindly suggest.....

Comment: So you have one `http://servername` web application in SP with AAM `http://portal.domain.com` configured. You did not extend the webapp in SP, just added an AAM, right? Q: What is port 14552? Q: How are bindings in IIS configured? Also could you please add some screenshots (webapps, AAM, bindings)?

Comment: i tried with AAM first then extend the WA, but facing same issue in both scenerio...   port 14552 is just  a default port of my dev site.(which is having same issue..)  Adding ss of Production site in the, pls refer the question..

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure `IP Address` can be empty in HTTP-bindings in IIS. Q: Do you plan to stay within extended web app model, or revert back to simple AAM-only method? Q: Do you need to map single `http://servername/site/sitename/` site collection to `http://portal.domain.com/`, or whole `http://servername` webapp to `http://portal.domain.com` like in pre-HNSC times?

Comment: 1. IIS Binding..  should I add server IP address !                                                       2. As I mentioned we tried first with AAM then we opted to Extened WA. so we can go back to AAM if problem is resolved,                                                    3. we need to map only single site collection with AAM address.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how 'HTTP redirection' you mentioned is configured, but https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2818415 is a very nice article that explains url rewrites - both symmetrical (`http://srv1/sites/site1 -> http://srv2/sites/site1`) and asymmetrical (`http://srv1/sites/site1 -> http://srv2/s1`)

If you want to be able to access `http://servername/site/sitename/` site collection by `http://portal.domain.com/` address, that's not quite AAM thing, but something covered by HNSC feature. Please take a look at this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx ('Convert path-based site collections to host-named site collections' section)